# How to reverse-engineer an Excel project that is using Macros and VB across many locations?

Tags: windows, excel

What are some common processes or tools to organize all of the macros, scripts and projects together in some sort of flow chart or in a way so I can create a flow chart? I have taken over a project with zero explanation, so I need to break it down. The project is very extensive in what it does and volume of data, while the developer was very against any standardization. There are also connections to multiple databases using I believe *MySQL for Excel*, with updates running on project open, close and built in function if selected.

Also, the developer had a habit of leaving unfinished projects, so I have to debug a bit. Creating a flow chart will give me some ideas of dead-ends, unless there are better ways built for Excel I am unaware of.